# "PhpDebugBar is not defined" error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to run login page of Laravel 5.2 project then found this **error.**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   (index):137
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: PhpDebugBar is not defined(anonymous
>   function) @ (index):139

**login html code is:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{!! url('/') !!}/backend/images/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo"><img src="backend/images/logo.png"></div>
    <div id="login_container">
        <div id="login_msg">
            @if(Session::get('success'))
            {!! Session::get('success') !!}
            @else
            <span style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Welcome...</strong></span><br>Please enter your login details below to authenticate.
                @endif 
        </div>
        <div id="login">
            <form  action="{!! url('/') !!}/api/auth/login" method="post" name="loginForm" id="frmlogin">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tbody><tr>
                            <td width="30%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Username</strong></td>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="login" class="login_inputs"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Password</strong></td>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="password" name="password" class="login_inputs"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%" align="right" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme"></td>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="rememberme" style="cursor:hand">Remember me until I logout.</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%" align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" class="button"></td>
                                            <td align="right"></td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
            </form>
        </div>
        @if(Session::get('message'))
        <div id="extra_info">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>

                        <td align="left" valign="middle" style="color:#FF0000;"> 
                            <span class="error-message">{{ Session::get('message') }}</span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div align="center"><a href="{!! url('/') !!}/forgot_password">Forgot your password?</a> or <a href="{!! url('/') !!}/signup">Signup</a></div>

</body></html>
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this error? Where I have done mistake?

Comment: Have you extend the layout view (with the blade';s `@extends`)? I don't see it here.

Comment: No @ Filip Koblański

Comment: Then you dosen't have these assets loaded. You're using from debugbar but you dont have any `<html>` tags...

Comment: Now I have update complete login page code. @Filip Koblański

Comment: call your file i.e.: login.blade.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123130/discussion-between-prashant-shukla-and-filip-koblanski).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue with these steps:

1. Composer update
2. env changed `APP_DEBUG=true` to `APP_DEBUG=false`
3. Then php artisan config:cache
4. .env changed `APP_DEBUG=false` to `APP_DEBUG=true`
5. Then php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 1):

Found out that another one might be required for AJAX calls (open handler).

According to this, complete app/Http/routes.php or web.php would now be:

```
    Route::get('/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets', [
    'as' => 'debugbar-css',
    'uses' => '\Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@css'
]);

Route::get('/_debugbar/assets/javascript', [
    'as' => 'debugbar-js',
    'uses' => '\Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@js'
]);

Route::get('/_debugbar/open', [
    'as' => 'debugbar-open',
    'uses' => '\Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenController@handler'
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If You are using Apache please the first check this steps. Mod_Rewrite allows you to make custom and simplified URLs as needed.

1. ```
   <Directory ***>
   ...
   AllowOverride All
   ...
   </Directory>
   ```
2. `a2enmod rewrite`
3. `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others cna learn from it. What makes you think that this problem is related to Apache?

Answer (score -2):

Check error log on server. It may be Disk space full on server then you get this type of error.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. A fill disk on the server usually does not cause JS errors on the client